# Virtualize RAID1 to proxmox virtual machine

Tags: virtual-machine, proxmox

I have standard physical machine which is Director for bacula. That means it just holds configurations and some data beside.

Is there any best practice for virtualizing physical machine to created virtual qemu machine on proxmox?

I was thinking best thing I can do is just clone configs and apps, but is there possibility of usage `dd` or any similar tool just to do bit copy and run it on virtual machine even thought the physical machine has RAID 1 on it?

Raid type is `mdadm`.

mounted filesystems (output of `mount | grep '^/dev'`):

```
/dev/md2 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)
/dev/md0 on /boot type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
```

*mdadm --query --detail /dev/md{0,2}*

```
/dev/md0:
        Version : 1.2
  Creation Time : Thu Aug 23 20:10:05 2018
     Raid Level : raid1
     Array Size : 975296 (952.44 MiB 998.70 MB)
  Used Dev Size : 975296 (952.44 MiB 998.70 MB)
   Raid Devices : 2
  Total Devices : 2
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Sun Feb  7 00:57:06 2021
          State : clean 
 Active Devices : 2
Working Devices : 2
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

           Name : dir2:0
           UUID : 1da015d3:c3443291:f4b63363:aec59730
         Events : 159

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8        1        0      active sync   /dev/sda1
       1       8       17        1      active sync   /dev/sdb1
/dev/md2:
        Version : 1.2
  Creation Time : Thu Aug 23 20:10:25 2018
     Raid Level : raid1
     Array Size : 217697280 (207.61 GiB 222.92 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 217697280 (207.61 GiB 222.92 GB)
   Raid Devices : 2
  Total Devices : 2
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

  Intent Bitmap : Internal

    Update Time : Wed Feb 24 01:02:48 2021
          State : clean 
 Active Devices : 2
Working Devices : 2
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

           Name : dir2:2
           UUID : 148bd7a9:a17e9e6e:d002c2d0:d7806567
         Events : 6779

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8        3        0      active sync   /dev/sda3
       1       8       19        1      active sync   /dev/sdb3
```

*/etc/fstab*

```
  # /etc/fstab: static file system information.
    #
    # Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
    # device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
    # that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
    #
    # <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
    
    # / was on /dev/md2 during installation
    UUID=7963eac4-4af8-4f02-8091-30887c83a10d /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
    
    # /boot was on /dev/md0 during installation
    UUID=b50673a9-beeb-46c5-accf-45778ebe6512 /boot           ext4    defaults        0       2
    
    # swap was on /dev/md1 during installation
    UUID=35e6df63-d091-4db4-88a5-5636a1fea96b none            swap    sw              0       0
    /dev/sr0        /media/cdrom0   udf,iso9660 user,noauto     0       0
    
     nfs     defaults        0       0
    
    dir2.host.tld:/mnt/bacula  /mnt/bacula     nfs     defaults 0      0
```

Comment: sorry for missing info. It is mdadm, I added it to the main post.

Comment: @roaima thanks for feedback, added output of that

Comment: @roaima added to main post